# How are handled the HTTP request using JSON in Spring MVC showcase? Some problems to understand

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

in this period I am studying the Spring MVC showcase example dowlodable form STS dashboard.

I have some doubt about some thype of rmapping (shown in the Request Mapping section of the showcase).

In the home.jsp view I have this two links :

```html
<li>
<a id="byProducesAcceptJson" class="writeJsonLink" 
        href="<c:url value="/mapping/produces" />">
        By produces via Accept=application/json</a>
</li>

 <li>
    <a id="byProducesJsonExt" class="writeJsonLink" 
       href="<c:url value="/mapping/produces.json" />">By produces via ".json"</a>
 </li>
```

The first link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **"/mapping/produces"**
The second link generate an HTTP Request towards the URL: **"/mapping/produces.json"**

Related to the **writeJsonLink** class I have the following simple Jquery callback function:

```javascript
$("a.writeJsonLink").click(function() {

    var link = $(this);                     // Variabile che si riferisce all'elemento del DOM che ha scatenato l'evento click (il link clickato) 

    // Esegue la chiamata ajax 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: this.href,                     // Indirizzo verso cui è indirizzata la richiesta           
        beforeSend: function(req) {         // Prima di inviare l'HTTP Request esegui la funzione passandogli il parametro req 
            if (!this.url.match(/\.json$/)) {                               // Se l'url termina con .json 
                req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");         // Aggiunge alla HTTP Request l'header Accept: application/json 
            }
        },
        success: function(json) {
            MvcUtil.showSuccessResponse(JSON.stringify(json), link);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            MvcUtil.showErrorResponse(xhr.responseText, link);
        }});
    return false;
});
```

What do this function it is very clear for me: **simply execute an AJAX call** and before send the call do a check to check if the URL ends with .json

Ok, in my controller class I have the following method which handles both previous HTTP Requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/produces", method=RequestMethod.GET,
 produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody JavaBean byProducesJson() {
    System.out.println("Dentro byProducesJson()");
    return new JavaBean();
}
```

The behavior of this method is quite clear for me:

**This method handles HTTP GET Request towards the URL "/mapping/produces" and the **produces*** element specifies that the method will not accept requests with the header named Accept incompatible with the specified MediaType and that this method produces a new object having JSON format that is put in the body field of the HTTP Response*

The new JavaBean object contatin only two inizialized variables and getter\setter method:

```
public class JavaBean {

private String foo = "bar";
private String fruit = "apple";

    // Getter & Setter Method
```

Ok...so a new JavaBean object is created with this variables value and this value are stored inside a JSON object that is put inside the HTTP Response towards the Browser.

Clicking on both link, in the browser appear me the same output, this one: **{"foo":"bar","fruit":"apple"}**

Now I have some doubt about it:

1. The first link generate an HTTP Request towards: **/mapping/produces**

   The second link generate an HTTP Request towards: **/mapping/produces.json**

   My method handles HTTP Request towards the URL having form: "/mapping/produces", why this    method handles also the second type of HTTP Request that end with .json?
2. The first HTTP Request don't end with **.json** extension so, when the previus Jquery code     is executed I don't enter in the **if body** and so the following header is not setted:    **("Accept", "application/json")** for my HTTP Request.

   Ok, the @RequestMapping annotation of my method contain the      **produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** element. For what I have understand reading the documentation this method have to handle the HTTP Request **only if in its header there is an Accept Header that contain "Accept", "application/json" as value**.

   This HTTP Request do not contain this header, why is it handled by my method?
3. What is the difference from the 2 type of HTTP Request? are handled in the same way? why?

Thank you very much

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seeing the effect of *content negotiation* by Spring. HTTP itself provides only one means for indicating the wanted content type for a response: the `Accept` header. Spring provides two additional means, through a content negotiation bean. It can interpret a URI suffix (`.json` in this case) as a request for a particular content type. The bean strips off the suffix before passing the controller class.